# How are epipolar lines useful in computer vision?

Tags: computational-geometry, computer-vision, image-processing

Why do use epipolar lines and what are it's benefits in computer vision ?I am unable to find the uses of epiploar lines and how they are helpful although i am aware of epiploar geometry concepts.

I would be so helpful if someone could pin point one or two uses of epipolar lines in computer vision .

Comment: Epipolar lines reduce the search space when doing stereo matching.

Answer (score 0):

When working with multiple cameras, epipolar geometry enables you to triangulate points in space, find the position of the cameras in space and more stuff addressing multiple cameras.

I can recommend to you the book "Multiple View Geometry" by Richard Hartley  and Andrew Zisserman for more detailed understanding. (Chapter 9ff)

Comment: "calculate the cameras distortion": what ??

Comment: I was wrong... the "epipolar line" does not make sense for single camera calibration... corrected the answer